# How to pass dataType as java objecttype while registering UDF, because calludf() returns Java object

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am trying to register UDF, where argument DataTypes should be Object type because I am returning a Java object while calling udf function (callUdf()).
But I found that DataTypes class dont have any objectType.
Actually I am returning a complex POJO object and the following ways are not working:

```
sparkSession.sqlContext()
        .udf()
        .register( "result", ( Row t1 ) -> {

                var result = new DataResult();
            var event = new Event();
            var attribute = new Attribute();
            List<Attribute> attributeList = new ArrayList<>();
            List<Event> eventlist = new ArrayList<>();
            for (StructField field : t1.schema().fields()) {
                String name = field.name();
                var value = t1.getAs(name);
                attribute.setAttributesMapProperty(name, value);
            }
            attributeList.add(attribute);
            event.setEvent1(BatchStep.LOAD.getName());
            event.setUser(System.getProperty("user.name"));
            event.setAttributes(attribute.getAttributesMap());
            event.setDateTime(new java.util.Date());
            eventlist.add(event);
            result.setEvents(eventlist);
            result.setDatasetIdentifierName(t1.getAs(DATASET_IDENTIFIER_NAME));
            result.setDatasetIdentifier(t1.getAs(DATASET_IDENTIFIER));
            
                 /*   return RowFactory.create(res.getDataPeriodicity(), res.getDatasetIdentifier(),
                   res.getDatasetIdentifierName(), res.getDatasourceCode(), att.getAttributeName(), att.getValue(), ev.getDateTime(), ev.getDateTime(), ev.getEvent1(), ev.getUser(), res.getInstitutionCode(), res.getRegulatoryDomainCode(), res.getReportingPeriod()) ;
 */
              return RowFactory.create(result) ;
        }, Encoders.bean(DataResult.class).schema());

@Getter
@Setter
public class DataResult {

    private String datasetIdentifierName;
    private String datasetIdentifier;
    private List<Event> events;
}


@Getter
@Setter
public class Event {

    private String event1;
    private Date dateTime;
    private String user;
    private HashMap<String, Object> attributes = null;

}

@Getter
@Setter
public class Attribute {

private HashMap<String, Object> attributesMap = new HashMap<>();

public void setAttributesMapProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.attributesMap.put(name, value);
}
}
```

So can you help me for this particular type of case where we are having nested java classes. How do I return javaObject of DataResult.class by calling UDF function.